# Derivative of determinant of square matrix-valued function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, determinant

I read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/623819) that

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{d}{dt}\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11}(t) & a_{12}(t) & a_{13}(t) \\
  a_{21}(t) & a_{22}(t) & a_{23}(t) \\
  a_{31}(t) & a_{32}(t) & a_{33}(t)
\end{vmatrix} &= \begin{vmatrix}
  a'_{11}(t) & a'_{12}(t) & a'_{13}(t) \\
  a_{21}(t) & a_{22}(t) & a_{23}(t) \\
  a_{31}(t) & a_{32}(t) & a_{33}(t)
\end{vmatrix} \\ \\ &+ \begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11}(t) & a_{12}(t) & a_{13}(t) \\
  a'_{21}(t) & a'_{22}(t) & a'_{23}(t) \\
  a_{31}(t) & a_{32}(t) & a_{33}(t)
\end{vmatrix} \\ \\&+ \begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11}(t) & a_{12}(t) & a_{13}(t) \\
  a_{21}(t) & a_{22}(t) & a_{23}(t) \\
  a'_{31}(t) & a'_{32}(t) & a'_{33}(t)
\end{vmatrix}. \end{aligned}$$

That is to find the derivative, we go go from row-to-row and find derivatives of each element in that row. **Is this true for higher order square matrices also**? If so, what is the proof?

Comment: The product rule works for multilinear maps (not merely for actual multiplication).  And a determinant is multilinear in its rows.  (Also in its columns, so you could do it that way.) The proof in this general form uses the "chin rule for partial derivatives".

Comment: The general case is knowns as [Jacobi's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).

Answer (score 1):

That's just the usual product rule. In two dimensions,
$$
\begin{align}
{d\over dt} \left(a(t)d(t)-b(t)c(t)\right)
&=a'd-b'c+ad'-bc'\\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
a' & b'\\
c & d \\
\end{vmatrix}
+
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b\\
c' & d' \\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Indeed, but my question is: can this row wise differentiation be extended to higher order square matrices?

Comment: @MangoPizza The way to extend it from two or three dimensions to more dimensions seems fairly straightforward to me. What problems do you envisage?