# Exterior Algebra: determinant and induced operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $A: V \to V$ linear operator where $V$ is $n$-dimensional vector space. Consider $\wedge^{k}A: \wedge^{k}V \to \wedge^{k}V$ given by $u_{1}\wedge ... \wedge u_{k} \mapsto  A(u_{1})\wedge ... \wedge A(u_{k})$.

When $k=n$, we know that  $A(u_{1})\wedge ... \wedge A(u_{n}) = det(A) (u_{1}\wedge ... \wedge u_{n})$.

But what can we say when $k<n$?

(In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant), they say that " Minors of a matrix can also be cast in this setting, by considering lower alternating forms $\wedge^{k}V$ with $k < n$.", but they don't give any reference.)

I'd like some reference to study it. Thanks

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604461/action-of-a-matrix-on-the-exterior-algebra/1605226#1605226). A good reference is Birkoff and MacLane's *Algebra*.

Comment: I looked it, but it doesn´t have this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Alladin what exactly does "this problem" refer to?  At the very least, the answer linked talks about where the minors of a matrix come in.

Comment: Another useful reference is Bhatia's Matrix Analysis.  One notable point is that the eigenvalues of $\wedge^k A$ are all (non-repeating) products of $k$ of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: When $k<n$, what we can say about $A(u_{1})\wedge...\wedge A(u_{k})$?

Comment: @Alladin what do you mean by "What can I say about..."?  That's really vague.  The answer link has certainly told you *something* about all that, but you're implying that there's something missing.  What's missing?

Comment: Sorry. It's satisfactory. Thanks

Comment: I like the answer below but would like to point out that this whole thing can be cast into the analysis of linear independence.   This is not relevant to the question but is relevant to the "meaning" of minors and forms.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604461/action-of-a-matrix-on-the-exterior-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Two good references are:

Bourbaki, *Algebra I: Chapters 1-3*, Proposition 10, page 529.

Birkhoff and MacLane, *Algebra*, pages 563-564.