# Name for determinant identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, determinant

Let $A$ be an $N\times N$ square matrix. There exists a determinant identity
$$\operatorname{det}\left(I+A\right)=1+\sum_m A_{mm}+\frac1{2!}\sum_{m,n}\left|
\begin{array}{cc} A_{mm} & A_{mn} \\ A_{nm} & A_{nn}\end{array}\right|+
\frac1{3!}\sum_{m,n,l}\left|
\begin{array}{ccc} A_{mm} & A_{mn} & A_{ml} \\ A_{nm} & A_{nn} & A_{nl} \\ A_{lm} & A_{ln} & A_{ll}\end{array}\right|+\ldots$$
Could you please recall me how is this relation usually named?

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137951/symmetric-and-exterior-power-of-representation/138794#138794, and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142164/determinant-of-a-sum, may be of help.

Comment: Neither an expert, but perhaps this? [*Fredholm determinant*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant)

Comment: I am less confident with my previous comment. As far as I know, Fredholm utilized the identity above to derive what is now called Fredholm series expansion of determinant, but I am not clear whether your identity itself is attributed to him or to anyone else...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jean Dieudonné in his ["History of functional analysis"](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mg7r4acKgq0C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%22Koch+formula%22+%2B+determinant&source=bl&ots=75xPo0F0Gt&sig=GdTxTxuI2azOrlKI1zhj4JeIrbw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqluSx-5fMAhVB1xoKHQS8ATAQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22Koch%20formula%22%20%2B%20determinant&f=false) refers to this identity as to *von Koch's formula*. There a [few more references](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22von+Koch+formula%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=qbgTV6fuJ4aLsAHKgpSoAg#q=%22Koch+formula%22+%2B+determinant) which seem to confirm this naming.