# Generalized Cross Product

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

I know that the cross product can be generalized as $$\text{cross}(x_0,...,x_{n-1})=\det\begin{vmatrix}&x_0&\\&x_1&\\&\vdots&\\e_1&\cdots&e_n\end{vmatrix}$$ where $e_i$ is the $i$'th standard unit vector. We have $n-1$ vectors in $n$-dimensional Euclidean Space, so there is a one-dimensional orthogonal complement to that set (if they are independent) and the cross product above gives a vector in that subspace.

I also  know that the "area"/"n-volume" of an n-parallelopiped spanned by the vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ is given by $$\sqrt{\det A^TA}$$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix}v_0&\cdots&v_n\end{bmatrix}$. In three dimensions this reduces to $$\sqrt{\det\begin{bmatrix}a_0&a_1&a_2\\b_0&b_1&b_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_0&b_0\\a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\end{bmatrix}}=\sqrt{||a||^2||b||^2-(a\cdot b)^2}=||a\times b||$$ I am wondering if it is true in general that, taking the cross product as defined above, $$||\text{cross}(x_0,...,x_{n-1})||=\sqrt{\det A^TA}\;\;\;\;\;\; A=\begin{bmatrix}x_0&\cdots&x_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

The algebra seems horrific but I can't find any nice way to prove (or disprove) it.

Comment: Which side of the parallelopiped are you measuring the area of in general?  Since I thought the volume formula was $\det (v_0, v_1, v_2)$ in 3D.

Comment: @EnjoysMath I am not measuring the area of a side, I am taking the "n-volume" of the whole parallelopiped. In 3D I found the area of a parallelogram.

Comment: Note this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706011/why-is-cross-product-only-defined-in-3-and-7-dimensions

Comment: @user137794 Thank you. In the accepted answer to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185991/is-the-vector-cross-product-only-defined-for-3d I am wondering how the author knows that "Then the magnitude of the cross product of n-1 vectors is the volume of the higher-dimensional parallelogram that they determine." I do not understand his notation or terminology because I have not studied those subjects yet.

Comment: @user142299 I believe he is essentially giving a definition to the cross product that allows it to be generalized in any dimensions. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n-1$ independent vectors for an $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelogram. (In 3D, two vectors form a 2D parallelogram). You can define the cross product of $n-1$ vectors as equal to a vector which is normal to all the vectors, and has a magnitude of that $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelogram they make.

Comment: @user137794 Right... I am asking if the cross product that I have provided in the post is in fact *that* cross product - if it's magnitude is the (n-1)-volume of their parallelopiped.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you wrote as your "generalized cross product" is what you meant to write. Try applying it to the cross-product of two three-dimensional vectors $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$.  You should be able to write the matrix explicitly showing each cell individually, not merely implying them by stacking vectors.  What is in that matrix?  Is its determinant the cross-product of the vectors?  Does it give the correct result for non-trivial test cases?

Comment: @DavidK Yes it is the cross product: $$\begin{vmatrix}x_0&y_0&z_0\\x_1&y_1&z_1\\i&j&k\end{vmatrix}$$ The determinant is not changed by two row changes.

Comment: I'm accustomed to seeing the notation $$i = \left[ \array{ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 } \right] .$$  In that notation, the matrix you wrote does not show each cell's value explicitly.  Did you try applying your formula to the cross product of, say, $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$ to see if it gives the expected result?

Comment: @DavidK I'm not sure if you are understanding what I wrote. See the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra They have the exact same formula.

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand that you were using a _formal_ determinant rather than the determinant of an  $n \times n$ matrix of scalar values.  In particular, of course you want the result to be a vector rather than a scalar.  I see you got an answer to your question in the meantime, and I'm glad you did.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, one defines $x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to be the unique vector such that
$$
 \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad \langle x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1},y \rangle = \operatorname{det}(x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1},y),
$$
where the determinant is being viewed as a function of the rows or columns of the usual matrix argument, i.e., as the unique antisymmetric $n$-form $\operatorname{det} : \mathbb{R}^n \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\det(e_1,\dotsc,e_n) = 1$ for $\{e_k\}$ the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, suppose that $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent, and hence span a hyperplane $H$ ($n-1$-dimensional subspace) in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, in particular, $x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1} \neq 0$ is orthogonal to each $x_k$, and hence defines a non-zero normal vector to $H$; write $$x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1} = \|x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}\|\hat{n}$$ for $\hat{n}$ the corresponding unit normal. Let $y \notin H$. Then $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1},y$ are linearly independent and span an $n$-dimensional parallelopiped $P$ with $n$-dimensional volume
$$
 |\operatorname{det}(x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1},y)| = |\langle x_1 \times \cdots x_{n-1},y\rangle| = \|x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}\||\langle \hat{n},y\rangle|.
$$
Now, with respect to the decomposition $\mathbb{R}^n = H^\perp \oplus H$, let
$$
 T = \begin{pmatrix} I_{H^\perp} & 0 \\ M & I_{H} \end{pmatrix}
$$
for $M : H^\perp \to H$ given by $$M(c \hat{n}) = -c \langle \hat{n},y \rangle^{-1} P_H y = -c\langle \hat{n},y\rangle^{-1}(y-\langle\hat{n},y\rangle\hat{n}),$$ where $P_H(v)$ denotes the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $H$. Then $T(P)$ is a $n$-dimensional parallelepiped with with vertices $Tx_1 = x_1,\dotsc,Tx_{n-1}=x_{n-1}$, and 
$$
 Ty = \langle \hat{n},y \rangle \hat{n} = P_{H^\perp} y = y - P_H y,
$$ 
with the same volume as $P$. On the one hand, since $Ty = y - P_H y$ for $P_H y \in H = \{x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}\}^\perp$,
$$
 \operatorname{Vol}_n(T(P)) = |\operatorname{det}(Tx_1,\dotsc,Tx_{n-1},Ty)|\\ = |\operatorname{det}(x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1},y-P_H y)|\\ = |\operatorname{det}(x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1},y)|\\ = \|x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}\||\langle \hat{n},y\rangle|.
$$
On the other hand, since $Ty \in H^\perp$, $T(P)$ is an honest cylinder with height $\|Ty\| = |\langle \hat{n},y\rangle|$ and base the $(n-1)$-dimensional parallelopiped $R$ spanned by $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1}$, so that
$$
 \operatorname{Vol}_n(T(P)) = \operatorname{Vol}_{n-1}(R)|\langle \hat{n},y\rangle|.
$$
Thus,
$$
 \operatorname{Vol}_{n-1}(R)|\langle \hat{n},y\rangle| = \operatorname{Vol}_n(T(P)) =  \|x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}\||\langle \hat{n},y\rangle|,
$$
so that
$$
 \operatorname{Vol}_{n-1}(R)| = \|x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}\|,
$$
as required.

---

**EDIT: Theoretical Addendum**

Let's see what $\phi x_1 \times \cdots \times \phi x_n$ is in terms of $x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}$ for $\phi$ a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define a linear map $T : (\mathbb{R}^n)^{\otimes(n-1)} \to (\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast$ by
$$
 T : x_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_{n-1} \mapsto \operatorname{det}(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1},\bullet),
$$
so that if $S : \mathbb{R}^n \to (\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast$ is the isomorphism $v \mapsto \langle v,\bullet \rangle$, then
$$
 x_1 \times \cdots \times x_n = (S^{-1}T)(x_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_n).
$$
Now, since the determinant is antisymmetric, so too is $T$, and hence $T$ descends to a linear map $T : \bigwedge^{n-1} \mathbb{R}^n \to (\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast$,
$$
 x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{n-1} \mapsto \operatorname{det}(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1},\bullet);
$$
indeed, if $\operatorname{Vol} = e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$ for $\{e_k\}$ the standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for any $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
 \langle x_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes x_{n-1},y \rangle \operatorname{Vol} = \operatorname{det}(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1},y)\operatorname{Vol} = x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{n-1} \wedge y,
$$
which, in fact, shows that
$$
 x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1} = \ast (x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{n-1}),
$$
where $\ast : \wedge^{n-1} \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the relevant [Hodge $\ast$-operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star) Thus, a cross product is really an $(n-1)$-form in the orientation-dependent disguise given by the Hodge $\ast$-operator; in particular, it will really transform as an $(n-1)$-form, as we'll see now.

Now, let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be linear. [Observe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/454723/49610) that the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\operatorname{Adj}(\phi)$ of $\phi$ can be invariantly defined as the unique linear transformation $\operatorname{Adj}(\phi) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for any $\omega \in \bigwedge^{n-1} \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
 (\wedge^{n-1})\omega \wedge y = \omega \wedge \operatorname{Adj}(\phi) y,
$$
e.g., in our case,
$$
 x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{n-1} \wedge \operatorname{Adj}(\phi) y = (\wedge^{n-1}\phi)(x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{n-1}) \wedge y = \phi x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \phi x_{n-1} \wedge y,
$$
and that, as a matrix, $\operatorname{Adj}(\phi) = \operatorname{Cof}(\phi)^T$, where $\operatorname{Cof}(\phi)$ denotes the [cofactor matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor_matrix) of $\phi$. Then for any $y$,
$$
 \langle \phi x_1 \times \cdots \times \phi x_{n-1},y \rangle \operatorname{Vol} = \operatorname{det}(\phi x_1,\cdots,\phi x_{n-1},y)\operatorname{Vol}\\ = \phi x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \phi x_{n-1} \wedge y\\ = (\wedge^{n-1}\phi)(x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{n-1}) \wedge y\\ = (x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge x_{n-1}) \wedge \operatorname{Adj}(\phi)y\\ = \langle  x_1 \times \cdots \times  x_{n-1},\operatorname{Adj}(\phi)y \rangle \operatorname{Vol}\\ = \langle \operatorname{Cof}(\phi)(x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}),y \rangle \operatorname{Vol},
$$
and hence, since $y$ was arbitrary,
$$
 \phi x_1 \times \cdots \times \phi x_{n-1} = \operatorname{Cof}(\phi)(x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}) = (\ast \circ \wedge^{n-1}\phi \circ \ast^{-1})(x_1 \times \cdots \times x_{n-1}),
$$
in terms of the Hodge $\ast$-operation and the invariantly defined $\wedge^{n-1}\phi$.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty epic and basically what I was looking for... the only thing tripping me up is how to rigorously justify the use of "Cavalieri." Is there any way to establish a connection (perhaps by looking at the special case of $y=\hat{n}$) between the magnitude of the cross product and the area-determinant formula from linear algebra?

Comment: @user142299 Please see my edit.

Comment: I sense that sheer awesomeness is happening - unfortunately, you're getting a bit over my head. Could you please clarify some points? 1. If $M(v) = \langle\hat{n},v\rangle\hat{n} -v$ then it would map vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n\to H$ right? And any vector in $H$ itself would be left unchanged? 2. What is the dimension of $M$ as a matrix? I see that $M(x_i)=-x_i$ but I'm not sure where $Tx_i=x_i$ is coming from. I haven't technically studied direct products yet so I'm just struggling a little to grasp everything you wrote... but I'm learning! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user142299 There's an error in the definition of $T$; let me correct it and make things clearer.

Comment: @user142299 The definition of $T$ is now correct. The way it works is that it fixes anything in $H$, and hence each of the $x_k$, but it's rigged to send $y$ to $P_{H^\perp} y = \langle \hat{n},y\rangle \hat{n}$, which is now orthogonal to the hyperplane $H$ containing the $x_k$. Explicitly, if $P_H$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $H$ and $P_{H^\perp}$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $H^\perp$, then
$$
 Tv = P_{H^\perp}v + (MP_{H^\perp} v + P_H v),
$$
where
$$
 P_{H^\perp} v = \langle \hat{n},v \rangle \hat{n}, \quad P_H v = v - P_{H^\perp} v.
$$

Comment: You know that $T(P)$ has the same volume as $P$ because the determinant of $T$ is one, correct? (Last question! promise)

Comment: It's worth noting that there's one subtlety in this definition, one that's bitten many a graphics programmer: technically, the cross product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or of $(n-1)$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$) isn't a vector; it's a _covector_: that is, a linear map from vectors to scalars.  There's a one-to-one correspondence between vectors and covectors, so we often speak of 'the vector' cross-product, but the catch is that the cross-product doesn't transform linearly under the same transform that vectors do; i.e., $(Uv)\times(Uw)\neq U(v\times w)$ if $U$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: @user142299 It is true that $\operatorname{det}(T)$ is $1$, but you don't even really need this, since $Ty = y - P_Hy$, where $P_H y$ is a linear combination of the $x_k$, and hence cannot contribute to the determinant by antisymmetry.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Take a look at the addendum for how cross products transform. The point is that they're really $(n-1)$-forms under the orientation-dependent disguise given by the Hodge $\ast$-operation (hence the physicists' description of cross products as "pseudo-vectors"), and hence transform as $(n-1)$-forms.