# find linear independent vectros in n-dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

First off, I'm not a mathematician and I'm getting a bit over my head here, so please have mercy on me.

If I have n-1 linearly independent vectors in n-dimensionas, I want to calculate an nth vector that is linearly independent to each of the others. In 3 dimensions I would use the cross product, which can be defined as the determinant of a 3x3 matrix where the first row is the unit vectors and the remaining rows are the row vectors of the 2 input vectors. Can this be translated to n-dimensions, where the result is the determinant of an n x n matrix constructed in the same way using n-1 vectors.

I've been searching the internet but dont really know what to search for and havent found anything. I wrote the following but don't know if it is valid:

We start with the following formula ([from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n_.C3.97_n_matrices)) for the determinant of an NxN matrix.

$\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{A}) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma_i} $

$\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{A}) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) a_{1,\sigma_1} \prod_{i=2}^n a_{i,\sigma_i}$

If the first row of the matrix is composed of the unit vectors of N-Space

$a_{1,i} = \mathbf{e}_i$

then we can write

$\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{A}) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \mathbf{e}_{\sigma_1} \prod_{i=2}^n a_{i,\sigma_i} $

**EDIT**

This may be a duplicate of [Generalized Cross Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752774). However, I do not yet understand the math in that answer, though I will work on that. The formula above is certainly in a different form, and I would like to know if it is valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generalized Cross Product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752774/generalized-cross-product)

Comment: Possibly, and I hope to eventually understand that answer, but for now it is beyond my understanding. The math in my equation I can understand, and I'd like to know if it is correct.

Comment: perhaps you will like this  [page](https://ef.gy/linear-algebra:normal-vectors-in-higher-dimensional-spaces) writen by someone having a similar question

Comment: @igael this looks very promising, thanks!