# Generalize Formulas to $\mathbb{R}^n$ from formulas from vectors in 3D

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, cross-product

I am looking for the n-dimensional versions of formulas for the
 questions below:

> •    Find equation of plane that passes through 3
>   arbitrary points of $\mathbb{R}$$^3$ that have 3 coordinates
>
> • Find vector equation of line that goes through two points in
>   $\mathbb{R}$$^3$ that each have 3 coordinates
>
> • Find the symmetric equations of a line through the point (a,b,c) and
>   (e,f,g) in the same direction as some arbitrary vector in
>   $\mathbb{R}$$^3$
>
> • Find the parametric equations of the line that passes through a
>   point in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ and is parallel to the vector in
>   $\mathbb{R}$$^3$
>
> • Find the scalar equation of the line through two points in some
>   arbitrary direction defined by a vector in $\mathbb{R}$$^3$
>
> • Find the scalar equation of the line through two points.
>
> • Find the equation of the tangent plane and symmetric equations of
>   the normal line to the surface $A(x-a)^2+B(y-b)^2+C(x-c)^2=J$ at the
>   point (q,r,t).
>
> • Determine the equation of the line that passes through a point in
>   $\mathbb{R}$$^3$ and normal to the plane ax+by-cz=k.
>
> • Determine a normal vector and equation of the tangent plane to any
>   surface with equation z= some polynomial at the point (a,b,c) in
>   $\mathbb{R}$$^3$.
>
> • Find the direction angle of some vector a$\vec i$+b$\vec j$+c$\vec
> > k$.
>
> • Find the projection of some vector onto another vector.
>
> - Find the potential function for del f = some vector function ai
>     +bi+ck.
> - Find the equation of the tangent plane to some plane at some point in    $\mathbb{R}$$^2$
> - Find the gradient, directional
>           derivative and equation of some tangent plane of some function with
>           three variables at some point in $\mathbb{R}$$^3$ in some arbitrary
>           direction.
> - Find the tangent plane and normal line to some surface
>           at some point in $\mathbb{R}$$^3$.

I have a really hard time understanding how to compute the bulleted items above. Many of the stackexchange questions/online questions ask us for a specific plane with numbers. I'm more interested and think it would be morehelpful if I found out the general formula. I'm wondering whether you can extend my bulleted questions into $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ and points in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$. I think this would help me understand vectors in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in an answer?  Do you just want formulas for each of those questions?  If so, Googling them one by one should provide that.

Comment: I'm looking for formulas in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which google lacks.

Comment: I imagine you could find the formulas in $\Bbb R^n$ as well.  But even if you can't, in many cases it's clear how to generalize the formula from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^n$.  For instance, the formula for the first bullet point is $$\mathbf r(s,t) = \overrightarrow{OP}+s\overrightarrow{PQ} + t\overrightarrow{PR}$$ where $P,Q,R$ are your three points and $O$ is the origin.  This formula actually works in $\Bbb R^n$, as well, but if you wanted to generalize it to a formula for higher dimensional flats in $\Bbb R^n$, you'd do it in the obvious way:

Comment: $$\mathbf r(t_1,\dots, t_{k-1}) = \overrightarrow{OP_1}+t_1\overrightarrow{P_1P_2} + \cdots + t_{k-1}\overrightarrow{P_1P_k}$$ where $P_1, \dots, P_k$ are the $k$ affinely independent points which define your $(k-1)$-flat.

Comment: These are not bad questions. But, how about **one** question at a time? Have you tried any one of them? Where did you get stuck? What difficulties do you have than there-are-too-many-questions-I-just-don't-have-time-to-finish-all-of-them-now? There is no silver bullet.

Comment: Do I need to know how to do everything in the bullets to study, curvature, curl, divergence, stoke's, green's theorem, vector fields, vector functions, cylindrical coordinates, line integrals, potential functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Rather than answer point by point, here are some useful generalities:

- If $\Vec{v}$ and $\Vec{w}$ are non-zero vectors, the angle $\theta$ between then satisfies
  $$
  \cos\theta = \frac{\Vec{v} \cdot \Vec{w}}{\|\Vec{v}\|\, \|\Vec{w}\|}.
  $$
  Particularly, $\Vec{v}$ and $\Vec{w}$ are *orthogonal* if $\Vec{v} \cdot \Vec{w} = 0$.
- If $\Vec{a}$ is a non-zero vector, then for every $\Vec{v}$, the components of $\Vec{v}$ parallel to $\Vec{a}$ and orthogonal to $\Vec{a}$ are
  $$
  \operatorname{proj}_{\Vec{a}} \Vec{v} = \left(\frac{\Vec{v} \cdot \Vec{a}}{\|\Vec{a}\|^{2}}\right) \Vec{a},\qquad
  \operatorname{perp}_{\Vec{a}} \Vec{v} = \Vec{v} - \operatorname{proj}_{\Vec{a}} \Vec{v}.
  $$
- If $\Vec{p}$ is a point and $\Vec{v}$ is a non-zero vector, then the set of points $\Vec{p} + t\Vec{v}$ ($t$ real) is the line through $\Vec{p}$ in the direction $\Vec{v}$.

  If $\Vec{p}$ and $\Vec{q}$ are distinct points, set $\Vec{v} = \Vec{q} - \Vec{p}$; the preceding paragraph describes the line through $\Vec{p}$ and $\Vec{q}$.

  The "symmetric form" for a line is a system of $(n - 1)$ equations in $n$ variables. The coefficients are any linearly independent set of $(n - 1)$ vectors orthogonal to $\Vec{v}$.
- If $\Vec{p}$ is a point and $\Vec{v}$, $\Vec{w}$ are non-proportional vectors (non-zero in particular), then the set of points $\Vec{p} + s\Vec{v} + t\Vec{w}$ ($s$, $t$ real) is the plane through $\Vec{p}$ parallel to $\Vec{v}$ and $\Vec{w}$.

  If $\Vec{p}$, $\Vec{q}$, and $\Vec{r}$ are non-collinear points, set $\Vec{v} = \Vec{q} - \Vec{p}$ and $\Vec{w} = \Vec{r} - \Vec{p}$; the preceding paragraph describes the plane through $\Vec{p}$, $\Vec{q}$, and $\Vec{r}$.

  The "symmetric form" for a plane is a system of $(n - 2)$ equations in $n$ variables.
- If $\Vec{p}$ is a point and $\Vec{v}$ is a non-zero vector, then the set of points $\Vec{x}$ satisfying $\Vec{v} \cdot (\Vec{x} - \Vec{p}) = 0$ is the hyperplane through $\Vec{p}$ with normal vector $\Vec{v}$.

Your original post had the "cross product" tag. It turns out the cross product has no generalization (as a *binary* operation) to arbitrary dimension; there is, however, an $(n - 1)$-ary "[cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752774)" in $\Reals^{n}$.