# $n-1$ dimensional permutation module for $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Say $n \ge 5$. Let $P$ be the $(n-1)$ dimensional permutation module for $S_n$, i.e. the permutation representation on $\{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in {\bf C}^n: \sum x_i  = 0\}$. Prove that:

- $\wedge^2P$ is always a irreducible $S_n$-module;
- $\text{Sym}^2P$ is always isomorphic to the sum of the trivial representation, $P$ and an irreducible $S_n$-module.

Is there a way to do this problem without using something "overpowered" such as Young tableaus?

Answer (score 1):

These questions can be answered with a little bit of character theory. If you can work out the character of $P$, then the character of $\wedge^2 P$ is not so bad. For instance look at the bottom of the second answer of this question. [Symmetric and exterior power of representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137951/symmetric-and-exterior-power-of-representation)

Once you can compute the character of the relevant representations, finding their decompositions is not so difficult. If you have questions, we can discuss in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Write $G = S_n$. Recall that $$\mathbb{C}^n = P \oplus \text{span}(1, 1, \dots, 1).$$Let $\phi: \mathbb{C}^n \to P$ be the projection and $e_1, \dots, e_n$ the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$. Therefore, $\phi$ is given explicitly as $$\phi(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (x_1 - \overline{x}, \dots, x_n - \overline{x}),$$where $$\overline{x} = {{\sum x_i}\over{n}}.$$Let $f_i = \phi(e_i)$.

The map $\Psi: \mathbb{C}^n \to P \otimes P$ defined by$$\Psi: \sum a_ie_i \mapsto \sum a_i(f_i \otimes f_i)$$is a $G$-homomorphism. Its image lies in $\text{Sym}^2P$, and it is injective.

Here is how to prove injectivity. Being a $G$-homomorphism, if $\Psi$ were not injective, its kernel would be a subrepresentation of $\mathbb{C}^n$; the only possibilities are $\text{span}(1, 1, \dots, 1)$ and $P$. In the first case, $$\Psi\left(\sum e_i\right) = 0 \implies \sum_i f_i \otimes f_i = 0$$and, in the second case, $$\Psi(e_1 - e_2) = 0 \implies f_1 \otimes f_1 = f_2 \otimes f_2.$$However, $f_1, \dots, f_{n-1}$ is a basis for $P$, and thus, $f_i \otimes f_j$ $(1 \le i,\, j \le n-1)$ is a basis for $P \otimes P$; this together with the fact that $$f_n = -f_1 - f_2 - \dots - f_{n-1}$$shows that neither possibility occurs.

Note also that $$\dim \text{Sym}^2P = {{n(n-1)}\over{2}} > n,$$and we have just shown that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of $\text{Sym}^2P$. Therefore, $\text{Sym}^2 P$ decomposes as a direct sum of $1$, $P$, and another representation $X$ $($not necessarily irreducible$)$. Consequently,$$P \otimes P \cong 1 \oplus P \oplus X \oplus \wedge^2 P.$$Note now that $\langle \chi_{P\otimes P}, \chi_{P\otimes P}\rangle \ge 4$ with equality if and only if $X$, $\wedge^2 P$ are irreducible. We shall show that equality holds; this implies that $X$ and $\wedge^2 P$ are both irreducible, as desired.

Let $\chi_P$ be the character of $P$, so that $\chi_P(g) = \text{Fix}(g) - 1$, where $\text{Fix}(g)$ denotes the number of fixed points of $g$ on $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Then$$\langle \chi_{P \otimes P}, \chi_{P \otimes P}\rangle = {1\over{|G|}} \sum_{g \in G} (\text{Fix}(g) - 1)^4$$$$= {1\over{|G|}} \sum_{g \in G} (\text{Fix}(g)^4 - 4\text{Fix}(g)^3 + 6\text{Fix}(g)^2 - 4\text{Fix}(g) + 1).$$Now¹$${1\over{|G|}} \sum_{g \in G} \text{Fix}(g)^j = \text{# of }G\text{-orbits on }\{1, \dots, n\}^j.$$It remains to count the number of $S_n$-orbits on $\{1, \dots, n\}^j$ for each $1 \le j \le 4$. For example, with $j = 3$, there are five orbits: $\{(x, y, z)\text{ }|\text{ }x,\, y,\, z\text{ all distinct}\}$, $\{(x, x, y)\text{ }|\text{ }x \neq y\}$, $\{(x, y, x)\text{ }|\text{ }x \neq y\}$, $\{(y, x, x)\text{ }|\text{ }x \neq y\}$, and finally $(x, x, x)$. In all cases, the variables $x$, $y$, $z$ are understood to take values in $1, \dots, n$.

We shall abbreviate this reasoning by saying the following.

> There is one orbit of type $(x, y, z)$, three orbits of type $(x, x, y)$, and one orbit of type $(x, x, x)$.

Reasoning similarly:

$j = 1$. One orbit.

$j = 2$. Two orbits: one of type $(x, y)$, one of type $(x, x)$.

$j = 3$. Five orbits $($as above$)$.

$j = 4$. Fifteen orbits: one of type $(x, y, z, w)$, six of type $(x, x, y, z)$, four of type $(x, x, x, y)$, three of type $(x, x, y, y)$, one of type $(x, x, x, x)$.

Thus,$$\langle\chi_{P \otimes P}, \chi_{P \otimes P}\rangle = 15 - 20 + 12 - 4 + 1 = 4,$$concluding the proof.

---

¹Indeed, if $G$ is any finite group acting on the set $X$, then $($Burnside's Lemma$)$$${1\over{|G|}} \sum_{g \in G} \text{Fix}(g)$$is the number of orbits of $G$ on $X$; apply this with $X = {1, \dots, n}^j$.

To prove Burnside's Lemma, note that $${1\over{|G|}} \sum_{g \in G} \text{Fix}(g) = \langle \chi_{\mathbb{C}X}, 1\rangle,$$ where $\mathbb{C}X$ is the permutation representation of $G$ associated to $X$. This inner product equals the dimension of the space of $G$-invariant vectors on $\mathbb{C}X$ $($why?$)$. But a function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ is $G$-invariant if and only if it is constant on each $G$-orbit; thus, the dimension of $G$-invariants equals the number of $G$-orbits.