# Character of $Sym^2(V)$ and decomposition into irreducible representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, group-isomorphism, characters

Let $G=S_3$ be the symmetric group on three elements, whose character table is given as follows:

[image]

Let $V$ be the unique irreducible representation of dimension $2$

**Question 1**: Compute the character of the symmetric square representation $Sym^2(V)$

The character of a representation is the trace of a representation. How could one find the trace of $Sym^2V$?

**Question 2**: Decompose $Sym^2(V)$ into irreducible representations

How do I solve this problem using *characters?*

I know that the basis elements are:

$e_1^2=e_1 \otimes e_1$, $e_2^2=e_2 \otimes e_2$ and $e_1e_2=e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1$

$\pi \otimes \pi$ acts trivially on $e_1e_2$, and $e_1^2$, $e_2^2$ give rise to $V$

So I believe we have: $Sym^2V \cong 1 \otimes V$

What I would like to know is: how could I have gotten this  result by looking at characters

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: for your first question you can see the answer of anon here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137951/symmetric-and-exterior-power-of-representation

Comment: There are many bases for $V$, and to check your computations, we need to know how $G$ acts on the basis that you wrote. So, how does the element $(12)$ act on $e_1$ and on $e_2$? How about $(123)$?

edit: Or, maybe this is easier: how do you like to think about the representation $V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** The character of $S^2(V)$ can be evaluated using the formula
$$ \chi_{S^2(V)}(g)= \frac{\chi_V(g^2)+\chi_V(g)^2}{2} $$
see for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/138794/149246) for a proof.
Then we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
  & 1 & (12) & (123)\\ \hline
 \chi_{S^2(V)} & 3 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}$$

**2.** If a representation is the direct sum of subrepresentations, then the corresponding character is the sum of the characters of those subrepresentations [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory#Properties).

It should be easy to convince yourself that the only way to obtain
$\chi_{S^2(V)}$ as a non-negative integer linear combination of $\{\chi_i\}$ is $\chi_{S^2(V)}=\chi_1+\chi_3$, which proves that

$$ S^2(V)\cong 1 \oplus V $$

In general the decomposition can be found using the fact that the set of irreducible characters is a basis of the vector space of conjugacy class functions.
The basis is orthonormal with respect to the scalar product

$$ (\chi_i,\chi_j) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \chi_i(g)\chi_j(g)  $$.

In our case $(\chi_{S^2(V)},\chi_1)=1$, $(\chi_{S^2(V)},\chi_2)=0$,
$(\chi_{S^2(V)},\chi_3)=1$, giving again the decomposition of $S^2(V)$.