# Character for kth symmetric and exterior power

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am trying to compute the character of $\Lambda^k V$ and Sym$^k V$ for V an arbitrary representation of a group G. I already know how the characters look for $k=2$, but I cannot find a way to generalize that. My attempt would be to find a way to decompose $\Lambda^k V$ and Sym$^k v$ into powers of 2 and 1, but I am not sure that is possible. Does someone have an idea to solve that?

Comment: Could you tell us what your result for $k = 2$ is?  I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "computing" the character of $\wedge^k V$ for an *arbitrary* representation.

Comment: We have $\chi_{\Lambda^2 V} (g)= \frac{1}{2} (\chi_V(g)^2 - \chi_V(g^2))$, and for the symmetric power the same expression but with + instead.

Comment: All right, makes sense now, thanks

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer: here is a a formula for $\chi_{\vee^kV}(g)$.

We note that $\chi_{\vee^kV}(g) = e_k(\lambda(g))$ and $\chi(g^k) = p_k(\lambda(g))$, where $e_k$ denotes the $k$th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), $p_i$ denotes the $i$th moment polynomial $p_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_i^k + \cdots + x_n^k$, and $\lambda(g)$ denotes the vector of eigenvalues of $g$.  [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) state that
$$
e_k = \frac 1k \sum_{i=1}^k e_{k-i} \cdot p_i.
$$
Plugging in the vector of eigenvalues into both sides of the equation yields
$$
\chi_{\vee^kV}(g) = \frac 1k \sum_{i=1}^k \chi_{\vee^{k-i}V}(g) \cdot \chi(g^i).
$$
This gives you a recursive formula for $\chi_{\vee^kV}(g)$ with arbitrary $k$.

---

To complete this answer, the corresponding formula for the alternating character (according to the [post linked above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/138794/81360)) is

$$
\chi_{\Lambda^k V}(g)=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{m=1}^k(-1)^{m-1}\chi_{\Lambda^{k-m}V}(g) \cdot \chi(g^m).
$$

---

If you look further along the Newton's identities page, there are further expressions for the elementary polynomials that could be applied here.  For instance,
$$
e_n = \frac1{n!}\begin{vmatrix}
    p_1     & 1       & 0      & \cdots       \\
    p_2     & p_1     & 2      & 0      & \cdots \\
    \vdots  &         & \ddots & \ddots       \\
    p_{n-1} & p_{n-2} & \cdots & p_1    & n-1 \\
    p_n     & p_{n-1} & \cdots & p_2    & p_1
  \end{vmatrix} \implies\\
\chi_{\vee^n}(g) = \frac1{n!}\begin{vmatrix}
    \chi(g)     & 1       & 0      & \cdots&0       \\
    \chi(g^2)     & \chi(g)     & 2      & \ddots      & \vdots \\
    \vdots  &         & \ddots & \ddots &0      \\
    \chi(g^{n-1}) & \chi(g^{n-2}) & \cdots & \chi(g)    & n-1 \\
    \chi(g^n)     & \chi(g^{n-1}) & \cdots & \chi(g^2)    & \chi(g)
  \end{vmatrix}
$$

Comment: How do we know the first formular?

Comment: It's a quick consequence of the fact that 
$$
\otimes^k V = \wedge^k V \oplus \vee^k V.
$$
If you'd like a reference, the formula is [given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_representations#Tensor_power), and there seem to be some nice textbooks referenced in the citations.

Comment: I had $\chi_{\otimes^k V}$ written incorrectly before; see my latest edit.

Comment: Can you tell me how you got $\chi_{Sym^k V}(g) = e_k(\lambda (g)), and $\chi(g^k) = p_k(\lambda (g))$?

Comment: What is $\bigvee^k V$?

Comment: @lisyarus $\vee^k V$ is $\operatorname{Sym}^k(V)$, in contrast to $\wedge^k V$ which is $\operatorname{Alt}^k(V)$.

Comment: Regarding those first formulas, those follow from the formulas for the eigenvalues of $\vee^k A$ and $A^k$ and the fact that the trace is the sum of eigenvalues.  For a reference, see chapter 1 of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*

Comment: If you mean $\bigvee^k V = \operatorname{Sym}^k V$, then the formula $V^{\otimes k} = \bigvee^k V \oplus \bigwedge^k V$ is wrong unless $k=2$, by dimension counting.

Comment: That's what I thought too

Comment: @lisyarus Thanks for catching that, I'll rewrite accordingly.

Comment: @S.Farr sorry about that; so this is a partial answer I suppose.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks anyway, maybe the formular for the symmetric power can be derived in an analogous manner