# Finding $\chi _{\text{det}(V)} $ for two-dimensional representation

Tags: representation-theory, characters

So I am trying to work out what $\chi _{\text{det}(V)} $ is for the two-dimensional matrix representation of $D_8 $ where $D_8$ is the group of symmetries of the square.

I have found the character table for $D_8$ but I don’t know much about this two-dimensional representation of $D_8$, I just deduced it’s character from the other characters.

Anyway, here $\chi _{\text{det}(V)}(g)=\text{det}(\rho (g)) $ which is a one-dimensional character.

If I could find out what the matrix $\rho(g)$ is for this two-dimensional representation $\rho$ then I could just find the determinant of it and that would be easy. But as I say I don’t really know what this two-dimensional representation is.

Comment: There is an obvious two-dimensional representation of your group which is precisely the one given by its action on the square! You do know it.

Comment: How is this two-dimensional? Do we view the square in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: Wait, so for $g \in D_8$ here $\rho (g) $ is just some standard matrix. So if $a$ is the rotation through $\pi /2$ the. $\rho(a)$ is just the standard 2x2 rotation matrix?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without knowing explicitly what the two dimensional representation is explicitly? Can you calculate $\chi_{\text{det}(V)} $ without knowing exactly what $\rho$ is?

Comment: What want to compute the determinant of something without knowing it?

Comment: There are formulas for the character of the exterior powers of a representation V in terms of the character of V,  which you can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137951/274) but you need to know the character of V.

Comment: (the usual action on the plane preserving a square is given by some *real* 2 by 2 matrices: just view them as complex matrices!)